# Not the same password for AWS (root user) and Amazon.com shopping, because that is not secure in my eyes

Tags: passwords, aws

I use the same email address for the AWS root user and my Amazon shopping account.

Unfortunately the password for both parts of Amazon is also the same, when I change the AWS password I automatically have the same for the shopping part.

But I want to have different passwords (but same email address), how do I manage this?

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to use different emails. There moght be no need to create a separate email account for that: many email services nowadays allow several alias emails in one account for such cases. For example, Google allows to create aliases like Josephine+admin@gmail.com on the fly: https://blog.101domain.com/business-development/gmail-email-aliases

Comment: Never used ProtonMail, so dunno) It's definitely possible at least for some paid plans, maybe for free also. Give it a try. Moreover, support page states you can actually receive emails on both your full & short Proton email address - give it a try, as described there. Be wary, however, that you might not (it depends on a service) be able to actually *send* an email from such alias. So, experiment a bit, check how it goes & how it suits you. If that'll work, let me know - I'll post that as an actual answer. https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/addresses-and-aliases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to use different emails. There might be no need to create a separate email account for that: many email services nowadays allow several alias emails in one account for such cases.

For example, Google allows to create aliases like Josephine+admin@gmail.com on the fly:
https://blog.101domain.com/business-development/gmail-email-aliases
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308648?hl=en

For ProtonMail, such aliases are available on paid plans, and free users can use their secondary address @pm.me:
https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/addresses-and-aliases/